# How to compare two indices in elactic serach

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I an running to am issue where I want to compare two elastic indices and find the documents missing from one of the indices.
I am working on ES 5.6
I have a logstash pipeline which is converting fields with "0" and "1" value to bool "true" and "false.
This pipeline takes an index named client-login, add another field with proper bool value and creates a new index client-login-bool

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "ELASTIC_HOSTS_PLACEHOLDER"
    index => "MIGRATION_SOURCE_INDEX"
    scroll => '10m'
    docinfo => true
    query => '
        {
          "query": {
                "match": {
                  "_type": "client-login"
                }
            }
        }'
    }
}
filter {
 mutate {
    add_field => { "bool_user_is_primary" => false }
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {
          "user_is_primary" => "integer"
        }
    }
    ruby {
      code => "
        account = event.get('user_is_primary')
        if account == 1
            event.set('bool_user_is_primary', 'true')
        end
      "
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {
          "bool_user_is_primary" => "boolean"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => [
          "user_is_primary"
        ]
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "ELASTIC_HOSTS_PLACEHOLDER"
    index => "MIGRATION_DESTINATION_INDEX"
    document_id=> '%{[@metadata][_id]}'
    }
}
```

This is the logstash pipeline the source index "client-login" have document with multiple type. I need to take only the document with type "client-login" add the boolean field and index the document in destination index "client-login-bool"
The issue is the document count in the destination index is not same as the document count in source index. Which is why I want to do a comparison and see which document is missed.
Also, if I remove the document_id from the output the document count is same.

Please help me out, I stuck on this issue for more then a week now and have exhausted all the ideas.
Thanks in advance!